# When does one get absolute value (or is it vector norm?) when differentiating? Why?

Tags: derivatives

Let $v: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, v=\phi(u)$ be smooth and convex.

Then

$$D^2 v = \phi ''(u) | Du | ^2 + \phi '(u) D^2 u$$

But why is there the absolute value (or is it vector norm)?

Comment: Since it's squared, does it matter?

Comment: @Arthur Well if it's vector norm, rather than absolute value?

Comment: @user474330 But where can I see the rule for chain rule and product rule for such vector valued functions? Because I cannot recall, why there's the norm.

Comment: Well, if $Du$ is a vector, I would see $(Du)^2$ as the scalar product of $Du$ with itself, which is the same as the squared vector norm. But that is maybe not a universal interpretation.